# Error Generating APK after Adding OneSignal Plugin to Ionic App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, onesignal

I just integrated the OneSignal plugin to my Ionic 1 mobile application project using the commands below;

```
sudo ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

However, when I try to generate an Android APK using the command below;

```
sudo ionic cordova build android
```

I get the following error below and I'm unable to build the APK;

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

What went wrong as written in my Terninal/Command Prompt was;

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/appdevmac1/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I remove the plugin again, I am able to build the APK. Puting the plugin back again produces the above error. Can someone please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to update your android sdk.

You can install and update each package using Android Studio's SDK Manager or the sdkmanager command line tool. All of the packages are downloaded into your Android SDK directory.

If you are using Android Studio IDE - [check out the instructions here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager)

OR

If you are using the sdkmanager command line tool, you can [follow the instructions here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

I hope this helps :-)